# Understanding python dict memory allocation

Tags: python

```
def func(bar):

    my_dict = {  
        'query1': 'select * from table1',  
        'query2': 'select * from table2'  
    }
    my_dict[bar]

func('query1')
```

My question is does my_dict executes both query and save it or it only executes query according to bar variable

Comment: What do you mean by "executed"? With your code, the only thing that could happen is that you could be referencing a value of `my_dict` if `bar` is one of the keys of the same dictionary...

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, no query are executed at all. It is only `str` objects which means that they actually don't do anything.

Let's try to detail 2 other cases. Assuming you have a function `execute_query` that execute a query given as parameter:

```
def func(query):
    my_dict = {
        'query1': execute_query('select * from table1'),
        'query2': execute_query('select * from table2'),
    }
    return my_dict[query]

func('query1')
```

In this case, both query will be executed because Python interpreter will analyse the dictionary composition. On the other hand, if you have a *reference* to this function, it won't call the function. Example:

```
def do_query1():
    return execute_query('select * from table1')

def do_query2():
    return execute_query('select * from table2')

def func(query):
    my_dict = {
        'query1': do_query1,
        'query2': do_query2,
    }
    return my_dict[query]() # <-- appropriate function will be call here

func('query1')
```

Comment: Good for you for figuring out what he's really asking about.

Comment: thanks man for the explanation. Actually i misunderstood the sql and string to same thing. I was using psycopg2 for database and there are different queries  according to parameter passed. What i misunderstood is that when i write the sql string in python dict it will execute it but this is not the case and it will only execute when i pass it to psycopg2. The dict will be the string not the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

That will create the dictionary with two elements in memory, find the value associated with key `bar` and destroy the whole thing when the function is competed.